# Curl progress function in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am wondering why this download() function is not working.

```
function download($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progress');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    function progress($resource, $download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded)
    {
        if ($download_size > 0)
            $progress = round($downloaded / $download_size * 100);
        $progress = array('progress' => $progress);
        $path = "temp/";
        $destination = $path."11.json";
        $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
        fwrite($file, json_encode($progress, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
        fclose($file);
    }
}

download("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

But when I am using without function like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://stackoverflow.com");
```

or when I am using the function twice like

```
download("http://stackoverflow.com");
download("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

it works. Otherwise it doesn't create any json file.

Comment: I wanted to create a json file but it was not creating. It works now after declaring the progress outside of download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your function `progress` outside of `download`:

```
function download($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progress');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

function progress($resource, $download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded)
{
    if ($download_size > 0)
        $progress = round($downloaded / $download_size * 100);
    $progress = array('progress' => $progress);
    $path = "temp/";
    $destination = $path."11.json";
    $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
    fwrite($file, json_encode($progress, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    fclose($file);
}
```